# How to use the SVN checkout directory in jenkins Source Code

Tags: svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I've the SVN main client at one server like XX.XXX.XX.12 and i've checkout the SVN on XX.XXX.XX.13 and i've installed the Jenkins on XX.XXX.XX.13.

Now i want to use the Subversion local checkout location in Source Code Management as XX.XXX.XX.13 [file:///C:/SVN].

If i use the local checkout location I'm getting the error as "Unable to access to repository" in Jenkins.

How can i use the local checkout location ?

Answer (score 0):

You specify an invalid URL to the repository. Double-check the URL, the URL must lead to SVN repository, not a collection or repositories or a working copy.

Comment: Is there anyway to have a working copy as SVN repository